# undefined reference to `_intel_fast_memmove' and `__libm_flt_rounds'

Tags: gcc, compilation

I was trying to use gcc to compile my C code (which calls python functions so I have to link to python libraries) with the following line

```
gcc main.c -o main.x -I/share/apps/intel/intelpython27/include/python2.7 
-L/share/apps/intel/intelpython27/lib -lpython2.7 
-Wl,-rpath=/share/apps/intel/2013/composer_xe_2013.1.117/compiler/lib/mic/
```

but got the following error:

```
/share/apps/intel/intelpython27/lib/libpython2.7.so: undefined reference to `_intel_fast_memmove'
/share/apps/intel/intelpython27/lib/libpython2.7.so: undefined reference to `__libm_flt_rounds'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could anybody tell me what could go wrong? Also I'm a beginner in programming so if there are any additional details that I should provide please let me know.

Comment: It probably makes no sense to use GCC to build an application linked against Intel mic coprocessor libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Those symbols might be defined in one of those libs:
-lm -limf -lirc